# Using jQuery Selectors, how to save those coordinates that I selected using cursor ?

Tags: jquery, html

Basically I have to keep tracking those coordinates I selected with using cursor but

I do not really know how to keep it using save() method. Can anyone please help..?

Here is what I got so far :

var newCoords = "";

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#theCanvas").click(function (evt) {

        if ($("#theImg").attr("points") == undefined) {

            $("#theImg").attr("points", (evt.offsetX + "," + evt.offsetY + " "));
        } else {
            newCoords = $("#theImg").attr("points") + (evt.offsetX + "," + evt.offsetY + " ");
            $("#theImg").attr("points", newCoords);
        }

    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {

      if (e.keyCode == 13) { save(); }     
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { clear(); }
    });
});

function save() // saves the shape 
{     
 // I have no idea this parts.. 
}
function clear()
{
    //Clears the points attribute. This will delete our shape
     $("#theImg").attr("points", "");
```

Comment: Where do you want to save the coordinates?

Comment: Any location would be fine for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function save() // saves the shape 
{     
   var offset = $("#theImg").offset();
   var sLeft = offset.left;
   var sTop = offset.top;



}
```

Comment: Could you think of any other ways.. ? I really have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You could save the values in data-attributes on the canvas:

```
function save() // saves the shape 
{     
    var offset = $("#theImg").offset();
    $("#theCanvas").data('left',  offset.left);
    $("#theCanvas").data('top',  offset.top)
}
```

And later retrieve them like this:

```
alert ($("#theCanvas").data('left'));
alert ($("#theCanvas").data('top'));
```

Otherwise, do like social suggests, except declare the vars in the global scope (not inside your function, or any other) and then *set* the values inside your save function.

Comment: Thank you sir, but where do I retrieve them ? Because I am basically making a website where users are able to click things that I selected on the image, when they get on the website. Specifically, I have background image as houses model and I need to select all those houses so users can select to see information on them. But for now , I just need to make them clickable. Thanks

Comment: Well, I asked where you need to save them, and you wrote "Any location would be fine for now" So I showed you how to do that in the DOM. If your question is really about permanent storage -- that's a big, broad question, and the answer could involve databases, flat-files, web-services, etc. Do some research on data storage and if you can't figure it out, ask a more specific question.